# Hiding div on change of checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi I am trying to use angular as well as jquery at the same time on the check box control. I have two checkboxes. Selecting one checkbox shows the respective div as each check box is associated with a div. Also only one checkbox can be selected at a time using my jquery function. The problem is when I select check box 1 it shows the div1 and when I select checkbox 2 although checkbox 1 becomes unchecked but its div is not hidden as  a result two divs appear on screen. How to hide the respective div using either jquery or angular. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
 <button ng-init="clickedh=false" ng-click="clickedh = !clickedh">Create Ticket</button>

    <br>
     <div class="main1" ng-show="clickedh">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkbox-2 = false" ng-model="DivTicket" class="subject-list" name="Subject" value="1">Create Ticket</input> <br />
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkbox-1 = false" ng-model="DivRefund" class="subject-list" name="Subject" value="2">Refund Ticket</input>
     </div>

    <div ng-show="DivTicket">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Welcome to Create .</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="DivRefund">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Welcome To Request.</p>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.subject-list').on('change', function() {

            $('.subject-list').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
            alert($("input[type='checkbox']").val());               
        });
        $(".subject-list:checked").each(function() {
            if($(this).val()=='1'){
              $(.)
            }
            else{

            }

        });
     </script>
```

Comment: In order for us to assist you, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The code you've provided has syntax errors and doesn't have any logic that would hide or show divs.

Comment: @RyanGibbs His `ng-show` on the divs are all the logic he needs to hide and show the divs.

Comment: @kam If you're using AngularJS there should be almost no cases where you need to use jQuery.  As Ryan said, there is a lot of code missing so it is really difficult to help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

As you want only one checkbox to be selected at one time why don't you use radio buttons.

I have made some changes to your code, see below

```
<button ng-init="clickedh=false" ng-click="clickedh = !clickedh">Create Ticket</button>
  <br>
  <div class="main1" ng-show="clickedh">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ticketCategory" value="DivTicket" class="subject-list" name="Subject" />Create Ticket <br />
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ticketCategory" value="DivRefund" class="subject-list" name="Subject" />Refund Ticket
  </div>

  <div ng-switch="ticketCategory">
    <div ng-switch-when="DivTicket">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Welcome to Create .</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="DivRefund">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Welcome To Request.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Working example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqtu5fLp/)

Comment: Well I need the similar behavior but its app demand to have checkbox so have to do similar thing with checkbox.